# Simple Rails Path Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a controller route defined as follows:

```
resources :watched, :controller => "watched", :only => :index
```

When I run `rake routes`, I get the following:

```
watched_index GET /watched(.:format) {:action=>"index", :controller=>"watched"}
```

For some reason, neither `watched_path` or `watcheds_path` seems to be defined in my views.  Any ideas?

Comment: Whoops, I meant to type `watcheds_path` instead of `watchers_path`.  `watchers_path` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your output from rake routes, the path you should be using is either of the following:

```
watched_index_path

watched_index_url
```

Comment: Yup, that was the problem.  However, could you elaborate a bit on why it's `watched_index_path`?  If it's a resource, why wouldn't it be `watched_path`?

Comment: A rule of thumb is this: rake routes is always the place to check for exact route information. Look at your output, the first column represents the route. Append _path or _url to that to generate the respective link.

Comment: Ah, I guess I was misinterpreting it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `resources` so Rails is pluralizing your resource:

```
> 'watched'.pluralize
=> "watcheds"
```

You can define a manual pluralization in your `config/initializers/inflections.rb`, but you should stick to nouns for your resources, since they're the only thing that makes much sense. Who is being watched? What is this resource actually showing?

Example of defining an irregular inflection:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'thesinglewatched', 'themanywatched'
  # or...
  inflect.uncountable 'watched'
end
```

Comment: In this case, Watched defines a polymorphic relationship between several different models and a user.  Therefore, I can't really say what's being watched because it's possible in the future I might have more watchable classes then I do now.  I didn't know about inflections.  I'll have to explore this in greater detail, because it sounds like a simpler way to accomplishing what I've done so far.  As for the pluralization, I mistyped in my original post.  I meant to say `watchers_path` didn't work either.

Comment: If you have a polymorphic entity, then the name of your resource can be `watchable`.

Answer (score 0):

try `watcheds_path` and let me know if this works